# Cover condition based return line in test case Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I am unable to cover on line in testcase I don't know how to achieve,

I have method in service as:

```
public getResults()
{
return this.http(url,body).map(this.mapResponse);
} 

private mapResponse(data){
 let cleanStatuFilter = JSON.parse(data[0].data.json);
 let cleanautoSuggestFilter = JSON.parse(data[1].data.json);

 return 
 {
     cards: cleanautoSuggestFilter.csAutoSuggest || [],
     actions: cleanStatuFilter.statusTracking || []
 };
}
```

I am unable to cover return statement in second function 
Can someone please help to cover

```
return 
{
   cards: cleanautoSuggestFilter.csAutoSuggest || [],
   actions: cleanStatuFilter.statusTracking || []
};
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: there is no error, but these lines are uncovered, I don't know how to write testcase for this line @SurenSrapyan

Comment: improved formating

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into the asynchronous jasmine tests using Done : [Async Tests](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html)